# Es posible conectar una aplicación desarrollada en visual basic 6 con sql server 2019

Tags: sql-server, vb6

tengo una aplicación con visual basic 6 conoectandose a una base de datos en access, ya migre la estructura y data a sql server 2019 pero quisiera saber si es posible conectar el aplicativo a la base de datos nueva en sql server 2019-

Comment: Probablemente si. Como mínimo deberías poder acceder mediante un conector ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que sí. Yo uso conectores oledb y me va genial. A día de hoy me conecto por igual sin problemas a sql server 2017 e inferiores con los oledb, asi que supongo que con sql server 2019 debe funcionar igual.